# Tools for Asynchronous Virtual Conferences in COVID-19 Aera

Tags: conference, covid-19

Due to COVID-19, we decided to move our conference to a virtual event. Since we have a problem in our community with different timezones we want to have not a synchronous event (i.e. a big telco with 100 participants), rather we want to have a asynchronous event where the participants upload videos of their talks, and for some time (e.g. 1-2 weeks) attendees can comment and interact below the video like with youtube (a hosting on youtube would not be an option).

I could programme a system like this by myself, but I assume that something like this is already out there -- out of the box.

Please let me know if such a tool exists! Or share your ideas!

Comment: One thing that I found already is https://lorros.com/l1/

Comment: Another one https://www.loom.com

Comment: https://www.panopto.com/

Comment: Also promising:  https://sproutvideo.com/

Comment: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/

Comment: Why isn't YT an option (e.g. with private videos)?